# Determining week number on a 4 week cycle in bash script

Tags: bash, date

what I want is a cycle of 4 weeks in a bash script
My question is: How do I know this week's number in the cycle.
    week x monday : echo one
    week x+1 monday : echo two
    week x+2 monday : echo three
    week x+3 monday : echo four
and again
    week x+4 monday : echo one
and so on

what I have is the epoch
(UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970
consequently
(UTC), monday, 5 January 1970 (I can set this to echo 1)

Any suggestions? Converting dates is no problem. Just a general idea is ok.

Comment: What about months with 5 week particular day cycle? e.g. Monday for Jan 2017?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expecting do something like this, with `GNU date`,

```
start_date=$(date -d "1970-01-05" '+%s')    # Corresponding to 1
end_date=$(date -d "2017-01-02" '+%s')      # Current week
```

Number of weeks between the dates

```
numberOfWeeks=$(( ( end_date - start_date )/(60*60*24*7) ))
printf "%s\n" "$numberOfWeeks"
2452
```

Now to determine which week this corresponds to, do

```
printf "The current week %s belongs to week %d" "$(date)" "$(((numberOfWeeks%4) + 1))"
The current week Mon, Jan 02, 2017  4:47:09 PM belongs to week 1
```

For further weeks down the line, say. 4th Monday of March 2017, using the above computation, i.e. with

```
end_date=$(date -d "2017-03-27" '+%s')
printf "The week %s belongs to week %d" "$(date -d "2017-03-27")" "$(((numberOfWeeks%4) + 1))"
The week Mon, Mar 27, 2017 12:00:00 AM belongs to week 1
```

Another example for the 3rd Monday or March 2017,

```
end_date=$(date -d "2017-03-20" '+%s')
printf "The week %s belongs to week %d" "$(date -d "2017-03-20")" "$(((numberOfWeeks%4) + 1))"
The week Mon, Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM belongs to week 4
```

Comment: I didn't test it but does it work for years with 53 weeks, for example 2015? (just asking, because I just fixed some of my production code that depends on modulo 4 and my last year's band-aid just broke...)

Comment: @JamesBrown: Haven't tested it myself, let me get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date output for showing the week number:

```
function printweek {
   weeknr=$(date '+%V' -d "+$1 weeks")
   echo "$((weeknr%4))"
}

# Test
for week in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 30 31 32 33; do
   echo "Week offset from today ${week} => $(printweek ${week})"
done
```

This will work when you start over counting each year (first week 1 again).   When you want to continue counting on 1 Januari, the script will be more difficult. You can look at the solution of @Inian.
Another option might be looking at the output of the last run, and add one `%4` to the weeknumber of the last run.